# Setting non-default HTTP headers with AFHTTPClient

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I see how to set default headers using AFHTTPClient, but I would like to set certain headers only when I perform requests to certain resources. Is there a way to this than building my own NSURLRequest (with the correct headers), creating an operation and enqueuing that operation to my subclass of AFHTTPClient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your network request are going to differ significantly it might be easier to create multiple AFHTTPClient subclasses to deal with the different cases. Adding your headers in in `- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url`.

Otherwise whenever you are creating your NSURLRequest with your AFHTTPClient subclass you are able to set headers with a few different methods:

`[client setDefaultHeader:@"key" value:@"value"];

[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];

[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"token"];`

You can set these before creating your NSURLRequest with something like:

`NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"someMethod" path:@"somePath" parameters:someParameters];`

Then your headers should only be in that request. You can also clear your authorization header using `- (void)clearAuthorizationHeader`. Taking a bit from the AFNetworking [source code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m#L401-403) you can remove any necessary objects from the NSMutableDictionary if they are not otherwise removed.

Comment: thanks keith. That is the method i'm currently using (multiple subclasses). looks like you are confirming that it isn't possible with one instance.

Comment: It's not that it's not possible to have different requests use different credentials (that's just to do with headers in the `NSURLRequest`), but it's certainly not recommended.